# `buildpacks` is not a heroku command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, buildpack

I'm trying to add a buildpack to my heroku app, but running

```
heroku buildpacks:set third_party_buildpack
```

returns

```
!    `buildpacks:set` is not a heroku command.
!    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

and when I run

```
heroku buildpacks
```

I get

```
!    `buildpacks` is not a heroku command.
!    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

Even

```
heroku help buildpacks
```

returns the same thing, and

```
heroku help
```

returns

```
Usage: heroku COMMAND [--app APP] [command-specific-options]

Primary help topics, type "heroku help TOPIC" for more details:

  addons    #  manage addon resources
  apps      #  manage apps (create, destroy)
  auth      #  authentication (login, logout)
  config    #  manage app config vars
  domains   #  manage custom domains
  logs      #  display logs for an app
  ps        #  manage dynos (dynos, workers)
  releases  #  manage app releases
  run       #  run one-off commands (console, rake)
  sharing   #  manage collaborators on an app

Additional topics:

  certs        #  manage ssl endpoints for an app
  drains       #  display drains for an app
  features     #  manage optional features
  fork         #  clone an existing app
  git          #  manage git for apps
  help         #  list commands and display help
  keys         #  manage authentication keys
  labs         #  manage optional features
  maintenance  #  manage maintenance mode for an app
  members      #  manage membership in organization accounts
  orgs         #  manage organization accounts
  pg           # 
  pgbackups    #  manage backups of heroku postgresql databases
  plugins      #  manage plugins to the heroku gem
  regions      #  list available regions
  stack        #  manage the stack for an app
  status       #  check status of heroku platform
  twofactor    # 
  update       #  update the heroku client
  version      #  display version
```

Note the lack of buildpacks in the help topics. My heroku version shows

```
heroku-toolbelt/3.25.0 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.2.4
```

Heroku's buildpacks page makes it sound like the heroku buildpacks:set command should work out of the box. Does anyone know why this functionality doesn't seem to exist on my machine? My app is in ruby (2.2.4) on rails (4.0.3) and I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem yesterday. It turns out I had a pretty old version of the Heroku CLI or the heroku gem installed.

What do you see when you type `heroku --version` into your terminal?

See the below from here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

```
 $ heroku --version
 heroku-toolbelt/3.43.9 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
 heroku-cli/5.2.39-010a227 (darwin-amd64) go1.6.2
```

> You should see heroku-toolbelt/x.y.z in the output. If you don’t, but have installed the Heroku CLI, it’s possible you have an old heroku gem on your system - uninstall the gem.

I ran `gem uninstall 'heroku'` and ran the installer from here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli
and then `gem install 'heroku'` and then the buildpack heroku commands started working for me.